# Swanky throws error on inititating smart contract:- error install deps "ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install' "

Tags: ink, astar

I'm trying to init a smart contract using swanky and i get this error below. I even tried changing my node version to 18.10.0.  It doesn't fix it. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: after switching node version, try deleting node_modules directory and yarn.lock file, and rerun the `yarn` command. (and also try `npm install`, maybe the error is more clear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix the issue. The problem came from the nvm installed. apparently, when you have nvm installed you can only install yarn using npm or else the node versions won't be installed on the same path and there won't be consistency. Since the default node version is controlled by nvm, installing yarn using curl or other ways except npm will cause errors, hence the error "no such file or directory: install".

To fix this issue: remove yarn by doing the following

1. `which yarn` which should output `\usr\bin\yarn` or the location yarn is installed.
2. remove yarn by running `rm -rf \usr\bin\yarn`. make sure to replace to the actual location on your pc.
3. now install yarn using npm. `npm install -g yarn`.

N.b this works for linux PCs

I hope this helps someone out there.